# How do I pivot columns?

Tags: r, excel, data-manipulation, columnsorting

I have found this dataframe in an Excel file, very disorganized. This is just a sample of a bigger dataset, with many jobs.

```
df <- data.frame(
  Job = c("Frequency", "Driver", "Operator"),
  Gloves = c("Daily", 1,2),
  Aprons = c("Weekly", 2,0),
)
```

Visually it's
[image]

I need it to be in this format, something that I can work in a database:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Job = c("Driver", "Driver", "Operator", "Operator"),
  Frequency= c("Daily", "Weekly", "Daily", "Weekly"),
  Item= c("Gloves", "Aprons", "Gloves", "Aprons"),
  Quantity= c(1,2,2,0)
)
```

Visually it's

[image]

Any thoughts in how do we have to manipulate the data? I have tried without any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/) methods by doing this in three steps

1. Remove the first row - `slice(-1)`, reshape to 'long' format (`pivot_longer`)
2. Keep only the first row - `slice(1)`, reshape to 'long' format (`pivot_longer`)
3. Do a join with both of the reshaped datasets

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   slice(-1) %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -Job, names_to = 'Item', 
       values_to = 'Quantity') %>%
    left_join(df %>%
         slice(1) %>% 
         pivot_longer(cols= -Job, values_to = 'Frequency',
            names_to = 'Item') %>% 
        select(-Job) )
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Job      Item   Quantity Frequency
  <chr>    <chr>  <chr>    <chr>    
1 Driver   Gloves 1        Daily    
2 Driver   Aprons 2        Weekly   
3 Operator Gloves 2        Daily    
4 Operator Aprons 0        Weekly
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(
  Job = c("Frequency", "Driver", "Operator"),
  Gloves = c("Daily", 1,2),
  Aprons = c("Weekly", 2,0))
```

Comment: Hi. I am getting this error: Error in UseMethod("slice_") : 
  no applicable method for 'slice_' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: @user284437 I see that you assigned the dataframe to `df` in your code.  Can you just type `df` in your console

Comment: @user284437 The issue is that if you have only construced `df` in this post and not having the object in the session, then `df` by default is a function in `stats` package

Comment: Yes, it says: > df
function (x, df1, df2, ncp, log = FALSE) 
{
    if (missing(ncp)) 
        .Call(C_df, x, df1, df2, log)
    else .Call(C_dnf, x, df1, df2, ncp, log)
}
<bytecode: 0x000002b8177af7f8>
<environment: namespace:stats>

Comment: @user284437 Thus, my quesiton is where did you create `df <-  data.frame(
  Job = c("Frequency", "Driver", "Operator"),
  Gloves = c("Daily", 1,2),
  Aprons = c("Weekly", 2,0)
)`

Comment: @user284437 I understand the issue now.  You tried to create the `df` with that code, but if you check the code, there is a `,` at the end, which cause the error in creating the dataset and thus 'df' was never formed in your enviornment